# KafkaTemplate for dead letter handler in Spring-Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Do I need a separate KafkaTemplate for DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer?

I have a KafkaTemplate used to send messages to Kafka and then I have a KafkaListenerContainerFactory with SeekToCurrentErrorHandler and DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer which in turn require me to provide a KafkaTempate. Do I really need this another template just for dlq handling or should I maybe use this KafkaTemplate for my normal kafka operations? I suppose I could also use a non generic KafkaTemplate for both but I suspect that is far from the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

If the generic types are different, you can either configure 2 templates, or use `<Object, Object>` (as long as your serializer can handle both types).